# Color markers to match stroke paint in Inkscape 0.91

Tags: inkscape

The new version of `Inkscape 0.91` doesn't have the `Extensions -> Modify Path -> Color Markers to Match Stroke` anymore. How do you color markers to match stroke in 0.91?

Answer (score 7):

They should just take the stroke color automatically.

After upgrading to 0.91 it first didn't seem to work for me but that was because I had selected one of the "pre-colored" markers that show up  in the marker list. After selecting one of the regular markers (below the horizontal line) it worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Until they fix the bug, you can copy the old 'Modify Path -> Color Markers to Match Stroke' extension from inkscape 0.41 to the extension folder of your 0.91 version. This will allow you to use this extension again.

1- download inkscape's source code [here](http://inkscape.global.ssl.fastly.net/media/sourceforge/files/0.48.5/inkscape-0.48.5-1-win32.7z):

2- extract the .7z file you just downloaded and go to the folder inkscape/share/extensions/ inside the extracted data.

3- copy the files markers_strokepaint.inx and markers_strokepaint.py to your extension directory. See [here](https://inkscape.org/en/download/addons/) how to find your extension folder

4- close all instances of inkscape and start again. You should get this important extension back. =D

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1431856).

If you login in launchpad you can click on the green link to show that it also affects you, that will give priority to the developers to fix it.